# Javascript param with special character

Tags: javascript, parameters

I have the following javascript function:

```
function Msg(strMsg){
    alert(strMsg);
}
```

i have the following button to call the function:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Msg('a"a');" role="button">Msg</a>
```

but since the `strMsg` passed param has a special character (") the function is not called.

The result should be: a"a

Comment: put a \ before " `onclick="Msg('a\"a');"`

Comment: Escape the double quote `onclick="Msg('a\"a');"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Escape character :

`\"` Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Msg('a\"a');" role="button">Msg</a>
```

You can try something with unicode :

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Msg('a&quot;a');" role="button">Msg</a>
```

Comment: in chrome, it changed to <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Msg('a\" a');"="" role="button">Msg</a>

Comment: @ImadAbuHayyah check updated answer i'll update proper answer for chrome